# javascript recursion find not returning

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function to search through an object for an element and return its parent array.  This code looks like it should work, but it only returns undefined, can someone explain why?

```
findInArray = function(el, obj) {

if(Array.isArray(obj)){

    obj.forEach(function(element) {
       if(element === el) {

        return obj;

       } else if (typeof element === 'object' && obj) {

         return findInArray(el, element);
       }
    })

} else if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {

    for(prop in obj) {

        if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object' && obj) {

            return findInArray(el, obj[prop]);
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You don't return from the `if` block. The `return` statement inside the nested function doesn't affect they outer function in any way. Here is a simplified example: `function foo() { function bar() { return 42; } }`. What does `foo` return when it's called?

Comment: @FelixKling can you elaborate?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, but your not calling bar?

Comment: 1. Shouldn't you first check if `obj === el`?

Comment: 2. I think you should also check if `obj[prop] === el`..

Comment: What do you want me to elaborate on (I mean that you are not returning from the `if(Array.isArray(obj)) { ... }` block) ? Also yes, I'm not calling `bar`.

Comment: @MjrKusanagi no as the point of the function is to return the parent array.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I still don't follow. in your example you're not calling bar at any point, in my code I am calling the function.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, but OK, lets pretend that `bar` is called one way or the other: `function foo() { function bar() { return 42; } bar(); }`

Comment: @FelixKling because I am calling it from within the `forEach` loop?

Comment: @FelixKling but surely I am doing this : `function foo() { return function bar() { return 42; }(); }`

Comment: To some degree, but it doesn't matter much either. The `return` in the inner function does not affect the outer function.

Comment: Nope, you are not:  `if(Array.isArray(obj)){ obj.forEach(...) }`. No `return` here. Again, what's inside the nested function is irrelevant.

Comment: @FelixKling could you modify the code so it works?

Comment: Got it, so simple lol.

Comment: 3. You need to return your forEach because it's inner functions output is currently being thrown away. Change that line to `return obj.forEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning from the first `if` block:

```
if(Array.isArray(obj)){
    obj.forEach(...)
}
```

hence the function returns `undefined`. If you want to return the value that the callback returns, you have to restructure your code.

It seems [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would be appropriate here:

```
return obj.reduce(function(result, element) {
   if (result) {
     return result;
   }
   if(element === el) {
     return obj;
   }
   if (typeof element === 'object' && obj) {
     return findInArray(el, element);
   }
}, null);
```

Comment: Why are you returning the inital value if it's set, surely it will always be set?

Comment: You mean `result`? It's only set if either of the conditions are `true`. It won't always be set.

Comment: Are you sure, I thought result is the initial or previous value of the array?

Comment: Right, and I initially set it to `null`. Then if neither `element === el` nor `typeof element === 'object' && obj` is `true`, it would be `undefined`.

Comment: Got it, missed that your setting it to null.